# Gmail contacts: With a limit of 250 per page, how do I view page 2 and further?

Tags: google-contacts

Gmail contacts has limit of 250 per page; how do I view pages 2 and further?

Answer (score 4):

At the top right I have forward and back arrows that select 250 at a time:

[image: WA73969 example]